# Object Class for Android Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin for Android. In order to make the plugin controls only visible if the selected folder is a project I added

org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject

as object class in the plugin manifest. However, this makes the controls visible for any Eclipse project. Is there a possibility to make the plugin only visible for Android projects? I did not find an interface like IAndroidProject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not be done through interfaces or "instanceof" tests. You need to make use of Eclipe's "nature" concept.

Basically, you need to call "IProject.getNature()" and check if that returns "null" (not an Android project) or an actual IProjectNature instance. If I remember correctly, the ID for Android projects' nature is `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature`.

Edit : Note that if you're trying to achieve this through plugin.xml declarations ("when" or "enabledWhen" or the such), you need to have a "and" containing both :

- an "instanceof" test checking for `org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject` and
- the test `org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature` that checks for the aforementionned String.

That gives something of the sort :

```
<and>
    <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
    <test
        property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
        value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature">
    </test>
</and>
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information.  I tried hard to do as you replied.  But I could not make it that way.  But then I googled my problem and found this.  I just added the tag                            <filter
       name="projectNature"
       value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature">
</filter>    which made the trick.  This workd fine.  Is that okay?  Or it is the wrong way of doing this?

Comment: There are usually multiple ways of doing the same things, the base idea was to point you towards the "nature" as it was what you needed; I then only gave you the example of how to do it in some places of the plugin.xml ... but depending on the extension point it is not _always_ through the syntax I highlighted here. If you found the way that worked for you, it is the good way :).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the tag given below to you plugin.xml:

```
<filter name="projectNature" value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature"> </filter>
```

It makes the magic.